# How to turn Magento 2 Maintenance Mode ON or OFF?

Tags: magento2, maintenance

I am not able to set Maintenance Mode in 2.0 version. Can someone tell me the steps that how to manage maintenance mode with magento 2.0?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In order to put your Magento 2 store in maintenance mode, you need to create one `.maintenance.flag` file and upload it under `var` folder at root of your Magento 2 installation.

If `var/.maintenance.flag` does not exist, Magento operates normally, and maintenance mode is off.

Alternatively, you can run below on your magento root shell:

```bash
# Enable maintenance mode
bin/magento maintenance:enable

# If you need to whitelist your IPs
bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip=X1.X1.X1.X1 --ip=X2.X2.X2.X2

# Disable maintenance mode
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Answer (score 30):

To enable maintenance mode you should create `var/.maintenance.ip` file. This file can contain a list of IP addresses. If an entry point is accessed using HTTP and the client IP address corresponds to one of the entries in that list, then maintenance mode is off.

Command usage::

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

To enable maintenance mode for all clients except 192.0.2.10 and 192.0.2.11:

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip=192.0.2.10 --ip=192.0.2.11
```

[Read more here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can `enable disable maintenance mode` and `exempt IP-addresses enable disable` for using below command.

**Maintenance mode Enable:**

> php bin/magento maintenance:enable

**Maintenance mode Disable:**

> php bin/magento maintenance:disable

**Maintenance mode Enable List of exempt IP-addresses**

> php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip=192.0.3.26 --ip=192.0.4.27

**Maintenance mode remove List of exempt IP-addresses**

> php bin/magento maintenance:disable --ip=none

Hope it help!

Answer (score 2):

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

...but...remember to purge varnish imediately after setting maintenance:enable, otherwise the pages will still be served from cache. Simplest way is `service restart varnish`

Then you can add IPs (e.g. admin's) that elide maintenance page: `bin/magento maintenance:allow-ips 192.168.0.11 10.0.0.5`

Clear the list with `bin/magento maintenance:allow-ips --none`

Finally, `bin/magento maintenance:disable`